# php find max value for both positive and negative value in array

Tags: php

I have an array i want to find max value for both positive and negative value.
 The expected result would be -13.2 and 7.8

```
$array = array
(
    [0] => -13.2
    [1] => -14.5
    [2] => -14.3
    [3] => -13.7
    [4] => -13.8
    [5] => -14.6
    [6] => 6.4
    [7] => 6.9
    [8] => 7.2
    [9] => 6.9
    [10] => 7.8
    [11] => 6.9
    [12] => 6.3
    [13] => 7.2
    [14] => 6.9
    [15] => 6.8
)

$maxrl='';
for($i=1,$j=0;$i<=count($array);$i++,$j++)
    {
        if($maxr <= $array[$j])
            {
                if(($maxr < $array[$j]) && ($maxrl != ''))
                    {
                        $maxrl='';
                        $maxrl.="L".$k.",";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        $maxrl.="L".$k.",";
                    }
                $maxr = $max_array[$j];

            }
        $k++;
    }
echo "<tr><td >'.$maxr.'</td><td>'.substr($maxrl,0,-1).'</td><>/tr>";
```

Comment: "The maximum for a negative value" usual is called "minimum" ...

Comment: It should return `-14.6` not `-13.2`

Comment: Do you mean the highest negative value, or the lowest? `$maxNegative = max(array_filter($myArray, function($value){return $value<0;}));`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran \ I think he wants the highest negative value, that's why the expected answer is -13.2.

Comment: If the OP wants -13.2 as a result, that would mean the maximum of the negative values. And then just `min($array)` won't work. One needs to split the array in positive and negative values and get the max from the negative ones.

Comment: @Barmar, So you're basically saying that all below answers are incorrect right ? ;)

Comment: Regarding the negative part: _probably_ yes. Depends on what OP actually wants, not very clear

Comment: The code in the question is very unclear. Why do you have `$i` in the `for()` loop, but you never use it? What is the variable `$maxrl` for? What is `$max_array`? You compare each element of `$array` with `$maxr`, but you never initialize that variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use max & min functions,

```
echo "Max Value:- ".max($array); // Max Value:-  7.8
echo "Min Value:- ".min($array); // Min Value:- -14.6
```

**UPDATED:** If you really want max from both negative & positive values,

```
$positive = array_filter($array, function ($v) {
  return $v > 0;
});

$negative = array_filter($array, function ($v) {
  return $v < 0;
});

echo "Max in positive Value:- ".max($positive); // Max in positive Value:-  7.8
echo "Min in negative Value:- ".min($negative); // Max in negative Value:- -13.2
```

Comment: `-14.6` _actually_ ;)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - Corrected. sharp eyes :)

Comment: But the answer he wants for the negatives is -13.2, the maximum negative number.

Comment: @Barmar - Totally agree with you,was just updating my answer.

Comment: Shankar - Thanks. We all just miss-understood the question on first look. Thanks to @Barmar :)

Comment: I too miss-understood the question but @Barmar :)

Answer (score 2):

For the positive maximum just take

```
$max = max($array);
```

The highest minimum is a bit more complex:

```
$minArray = array();
foreach ( $array as $val )
    if ( $val < 0 )
       $minArray[] = $val;

$min = max($minArray);
```

If I get the OPs question right

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `max` and `min` methods specifically for this

```
$max = max($array); // 7.8
$min = min($array); // -14.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//$dd = array(-50, -25, -5, -80, -40, -152, -45, -28, -455, -100, -98, -455);
$dd = array(50, -25, -5, 80, -40, -152, -45, 28, -455, 100, 98, -455);
//$dd = array(50, 25, 5, 80, 40, 152, 45, 28, 455, 100, 98, 455);
$curr = '';
$max = $dd[0];

for($i = 0; $i < count($dd); $i++) {
    $curr = $dd[$i];

    if($curr >= $max) {
        $max = $curr;   
    }
}

echo "greatest number is $max";
```

Answer (score -3):

Just do:

```
$max = max($array);
$min = min($array);
```

Much easier! ;)

Comment: Why the -1? This is the standard way of doing it!